# iPhone : How to convert date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

My date is coming in string format  from server

Output of date come like this "07/30/2011",

I want a date format "30 july"

how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"07/30/2011" ];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *output = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```